# Is $Z(w)=\left\{\begin{matrix} X(w)& \mbox{if} \ Y(w)\geq 0 \\ -X(w)& \mbox{if} \ Y(w)<0 \end{matrix}\right.$ a random variable?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Hi I have one small question:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be standard normally distributed random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and define

$Z(w)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 X(w)& \mbox{if}\ Y(w)\geq 0 \\ 
 -X(w)&\mbox{if} \ Y(w)<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

My question is: is this a random variable? If yes, why, if no, why not?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random variable is just any (measurable) function on a probability space. The formula that determines a random variable from a given input $\omega$ can be entirely deterministic; the element of randomness comes from the fact that we imagine not knowing which input $\omega$ was drawn.

So: yes, the formula you described is, indeed, a random variable.

Comment: In particular, a measurable function of random variables is itself a random variable, and that includes the construction in the OP.